# How do I detect SD card insertion (just the SD card, not the card reader) in Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, sd-card, memory-card

I have a headless debian (3.2.0-3-686-pae) to which I wanted to attach a standalone card reader to automatically process my pictures. The idea is that the reader will be plugged in all the time and I would just insert the SD card.

Unfortunately the card is not detected when I insert it.

- the card reader is correctly recognized
- when I connect the card reader with the SD card already inserted both are correctly recognized and the card is automatically mounted.

Therefore this is the action of inserting the card into a working card reader which is not recognized. There are no messages in /var/log/messages (nor anywhere else). When the card reader is inserted the messages are correct:

```
Aug  4 14:25:03 server kernel: [711743.411320] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 5
Aug  4 14:25:12 server kernel: [711751.964021] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
Aug  4 14:25:12 server kernel: [711752.097364] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6366
Aug  4 14:25:12 server kernel: [711752.097369] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Aug  4 14:25:12 server kernel: [711752.097373] usb 1-6: Product: Mass Storage Device
Aug  4 14:25:12 server kernel: [711752.097375] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Generic
Aug  4 14:25:12 server kernel: [711752.097377] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 058F63666433
Aug  4 14:25:12 server kernel: [711752.098062] scsi4 : usb-storage 1-6:1.0
Aug  4 14:25:13 server kernel: [711753.224612] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Multiple Card  Reader     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Aug  4 14:25:14 server kernel: [711753.810820] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 1984000 512-byte logical blocks: (1.01 GB/968 MiB)
Aug  4 14:25:14 server kernel: [711753.811559] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Aug  4 14:25:14 server kernel: [711753.829719]  sdc: sdc1
Aug  4 14:25:14 server kernel: [711753.840025] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I was wondering if I am missing something somewhere (the behavior above is out of the box - I did not need to configure anything) **-or-** that the insertion of a card into an already-connected card reader is simply not recognized by design.

---

**EDIT**: While fora discussions claim that the lack of message is normal, it obviously works for some (thanks Piskvor nad darnir for the comments).
I will leave the question unanswered and file a bug with Debian - updating this post if there is any progress.

**EDIT**: filed [Bug#684306](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684306) (bugs.debian.org)

Comment: I can't find the original mails atm, but a year ago there was a discussion about this on a the FreeBSD mailing lists. The answer was that insertion can not be detected by the hardware. (or as you write: not recognized by design). The only workaround was to poll the device.

Comment: Hmmm...the card insertion event generates a "detected capacity change from 0 to 123456789" line in syslog for me (where 123456789 is card capacity in bytes, IIRC); not sure what is generating this (logged as "kernel").

Comment: @Piskvor: ah this is interesting. Which kernel are you on? I log everything and do not see this kind of message

Comment: @WoJ: 3.2.0-27; I currently don't have a SD card to try this and post the exact message.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I've solved this problem:

1. Install the udisks package
2. Run udisks --poll-for-media

Via a udev rule I then trigger a script that takes care of downloading the data from my CF card automatically.

Comment: udisks does not exists anymore in most linux OS distros.

Comment: @AdrianMaire it exists on Fedora, just installed it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that polling for block devices are disabled.

check this value

```
cat /sys/module/block/parameters/events_dfl_poll_msecs
```

is its 0, make it 2000

```
echo 2000 > /sys/module/block/parameters/events_dfl_poll_msecs
```

Now run time detection should work.

Usually, the udev rules contain attributes to write 2000 at this node. So if that udev package is missing, install it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: please disregard (see edit in the main question). I leave the "answer" so that the comments can refer to something)

> Well, after having done a round through various fora it looks like
>   that this is currently not possible. It looks like there is,
>   technically, a way to have it done (as the insertion generates
>   specific HW events) but this is not implemented. This is quite
>   unfortunate as there are plenty of possible applications. In my case
>   this is not too bad as the card reader is standalone but it gest
>   tricky for built-in ones (though maybe in that case this is handled
>   differently, I do not know as I do no have one)

Comment: I tried it on Arch and I have an entry in dmesg on card insertion/removal with the reader already plugged in. So, it is possible, out-of-the-box on the vanilla kernel.

Comment: @darnir: what message do you get? Something similar to Piskvor's one (above)

Comment: dmesg output: [ 4366.893775] r592: IRQ: card removed
[ 4375.765801] r592: IRQ: card added
[ 4376.519845] memstick0: switching to 4-bit parallel mode
[ 4376.523049]  mspblk0: p1